# How to set locale in Docker Alpine?

Tags: docker, centos, locale, alpine-linux

I can set locale with CentOS image with

```
FROM centos

ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8

ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
```

But It seems not work with Alpine image. How can I set locale with Alpine image?

Comment: The default image doesn't seem to support it, see: https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/144

Answer (score 12):

It works for me, Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

RUN apk update
RUN apk add tzdata
RUN cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Sao_Paulo /etc/localtime
RUN rm -r /usr/share/zoneinfo/Africa && \
    rm -r /usr/share/zoneinfo/Antarctica && \
    rm -r /usr/share/zoneinfo/Arctic && \
    rm -r /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia && \
    rm -r /usr/share/zoneinfo/Atlantic && \
    rm -r /usr/share/zoneinfo/Australia && \
    rm -r /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe  && \
    rm -r /usr/share/zoneinfo/Indian && \
    rm -r /usr/share/zoneinfo/Mexico && \
    rm -r /usr/share/zoneinfo/Pacific && \
    rm -r /usr/share/zoneinfo/Chile && \
    rm -r /usr/share/zoneinfo/Canada
RUN echo "America/Sao_Paulo" >  /etc/timezone

ENV TZ America/Sao_Paulo
ENV LANG pt_BR.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE pt_BR.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL pt_BR.UTF-8

ARG JAR_FILE
ADD ${JAR_FILE} /app/
RUN mv /app/${JAR_FILE} /app/app.jar
ENTRYPOINT java $JAVA_OPTS -jar /app/app.jar
```

Comment: Removing the unneeded files in the way you do doesn't really reduce the size of the image. If that is the intention, gather them in one RUN and use `&&` between the commands.

Comment: Works for me, thank you !!!

I didn't need to remove zoneInfos with rm command, my docker file:


`
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jre-alpine
RUN apk update
RUN apk add tzdata
RUN cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Recife /etc/localtime
RUN echo "America/Recife" >  /etc/timezone
ENV TZ America/Recife
ENV LANG pt_BR.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE pt_BR.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL pt_BR.UTF-8
COPY --from=builder app/target/app*.war app.war
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.war"]
`

Answer (score 9):

This is how I setup my time & encodings when containerizing an application in Alpine Linux.

The following is tested and known to work correctly as of Alpine Linux version 3.16:

In the `Dockerfile`:

Install required packages:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache --update musl musl-utils musl-locales tzdata
```

Set timezone from the choices in  `/usr/share/zoneinfo/`:

```
ENV TZ=Europe/London
RUN cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/London /etc/localtime
```

In `/usr/share/i18n/locales/musl`, `Musl` will install the following encodings:

```
cs_CZ.UTF-8
de_CH.UTF-8
de_DE.UTF-8
en_GB.UTF-8
en_US.UTF-8
es_ES.UTF-8
fi_FI.UTF-8
fr_FR.UTF-8
it_IT.UTF-8
nb_NO.UTF-8
nl_NL.UTF-8
pt_BR.UTF-8
pt_PT.UTF-8
ru_RU.UTF-8
sr_RS.UTF-8
sv_SE.UTF-8
```

Choose your preferred encoding from the above list and substitute it for `en_GB.UTF-8` if you don't want GB English in the following lines of your Dockerfile:

```
RUN echo 'export LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8' >> /etc/profile.d/locale.sh && \
  sed -i 's|LANG=C.UTF-8|LANG=en_GB.UTF-8|' /etc/profile.d/locale.sh
```

Although you have to `sed` the `LANG=` parameter, by appending `export LC_ALL=` to the end of `/etc/profile.d/locale.sh` the rest is done for you.

After the build, when you now execute:

```
locale
```

You'll see the default encodings have changed **FROM** `C.UTF-8` **TO** `en_GB.UTF-8`:

```
bash-5.1# locale
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8
bash-5.1#
```

And when you execute:

```
date
```

You'll note the the time has now changed **FROM** `UTC` **TO** `BST`:

```
Mon Jul 18 16:59:51 BST 2022
```

Finally, some notes worth reading on Alpine's `Musl` implementation of locales is [HERE](https://wiki.musl-libc.org/open-issues.html)

Answer (score 3):

There is a cleaner way using `apk del tzdata`, described here:

[Setting the timezone - Alpine Linux](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Setting_the_timezone)

Comment: First you need to install the page (`apk add`), configure the timezone, and optionally remove the package. But this is not what OP was asking for.

Comment: this is only for `uclibc`, not `musl` or `glibc`