# Localization using TZ/LANG env variable works in ASP.NET Core Debian image but not in Alpine

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, localization

To force German localization, I set `TZ=Europe/Berlin` and `LANG=de_DE.UTF-8` in my `docker-compose.yml` file. I verified the culture by printing it in my `_Layout.cshtml` file

```
@System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name
```

This works on the default 2.1 image. Now I migrated to the alpine image to reduce size and attack surface. Now `DateTime` objects behave strange: `CurrentCulture.Name` gaves `de-DE`  when [forcing them in DI and the current thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40442444/set-cultureinfo-in-asp-net-core-to-have-a-as-currencydecimalseparator-instead). But I still have US time format, for example `/` instead of `.` as delimiter. `CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator` also prints `/`, even it's a `de` culture which should have a dot.

I could verify this by removing any localization code from `Startup.cs`. Now there is *no* call to `app.UseRequestLocalization` or `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture`. The Dockerfile used for building:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.1-alpine AS sdk-image
WORKDIR /app/MyApp
COPY MyApp.csproj .

# Copied by Jenkins since nuget.config must be on solution level for Visual Studio to work, not project level
COPY nuget.config .
RUN dotnet restore --configfile nuget.config

COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish -c Debug -o /publish

# In the alpine image, the localization from TZ/LANG env variables seems ignored
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.1 AS runtime-image
COPY --from=sdk-image /publish .
ARG ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://0.0.0.0:5000
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=${ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT}
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.dll"]
```

This Dockerfile works fine. Now lets replace

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.1 AS runtime-image
```

with

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.1-alpine AS runtime-image
```

and the described behavior occurs: `CurrentCulture` is `de` but with `/` instead of `.` delimiter.

#### Why does this happen in the alpine image and how could it be fixed?

Are there some dependencies missing in alpine to let ASP.NET Core detect the localization correctly?

Comment: AFAIK alpine does not support setting `LANG` well. See https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/144 .

Comment: Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53820235/2501279) answer.

Comment: To set the TimeZone in the alpine image you must add the package tzdata in your alpine image (`RUN apk add --no-cache tzdata`) after that you can set the TimeZone over the enviorment variable `TZ=Europe/Berlin`